# PHP session losing data between pages

Tags: php, session

I am trying to set up a login system for my website that requires someone to be logged in in order to post.  I have set it up with sessions and it works great on my localhost but not on the server.  I set up print_r(session) on some of the pages to see where the data loss is.  On the page checklogin.php, which is the page that gets run when someone logs in, it works fine.  Here is some code from there:

```
<?php
session_name('login_session');
session_start();

mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("date_ideas") or die(mysql_error());

$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$uname=mysql_real_escape_string($uname);
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$pass=mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
$pass=md5($pass);

$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='$uname' AND pass='$pass'";

$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $numrows;

if ($numrows==1)
{
$_SESSION['login']="1";
$_SESSION['uname']=$uname;
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('match');</script>";
print_r($_SESSION);
}
else
{
$_SESSION['login']="";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid Login');</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'login.php?uname=$uname'</script>";
}
?>
```

When I submit the form with good login information, the alert pops up and the print returns:

> Array ( [login] => 1 [uname] => FrizbeeFanatic14 )

So at that point it's working.  However, when I go to the main page, the print becomes:

> Array ( )

So it has lost the session information.  Here is the code from the main page:

```
<?php
session_name('login_session');
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Great Date Ideas</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cookiecheck.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
<script type="text/javascript">
if (detect=false)
{
document.write("You must enable cookies to view this page.");
window.stop();
document.execCommand('Stop');
}
</script>
<div id="home"><?php require("header.php");?></div>
<?php
print_r($_SESSION);
mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("date_ideas") or die(mysql_error());

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ideas ORDER BY post_date DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

It goes on, but what follows works fine.

So all this code works just fine on my localhost, but on the server I get this error.

Comment: You need two equal instead of one  in `if (detect=false)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem - the save directory for the PHP sessions was a root apache directory, and I'm runnin nginx fastcgi.  I just changed the root permissions for the folder and it works.  Thanks a ton for all of your help.

Answer (score 4):

The only time I´ve had a similar problem, was when I was accidentally changing the domain while going to another page (from `www.mydomain.com` to`mydomain.com` and the other way around).

You can have your session persist between different sub-domains using [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php):

```
session_name('login_session');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.mydomain.com');
session_start();
```

**Edit:** Perhaps this can help you: A very interesting article: [PHP Session Debugging](http://shiflett.org/blog/2011/mar/php-session-debugging)

Comment: This I mean when I say session path :)

Comment: Where would I put that code?  At the beginning of index.php? or all of them?

Comment: I put that at the beginning of both index.php and checklogin.php, and it made no change.

Comment: @FrizbeeFanatic14 Just to be sure, you have replaced `.mydomain.com` with `.your_real_domain`, right? Note that it needs to start with a dot.

Comment: Yes I did.  The URL for my website (currently) is ryan.seanhess.net.  I replaced `.mydomain.com` with `seanhess.net`

Comment: @FrizbeeFanatic14 I hope you mean `.seanhess.net` (with the dot at the start). Anyway, then I´m afraid I don´t know why it´s not working, although you could try the same with `.ryan.seanhess.net`, just in case...

Comment: @jeroen Yeah, it is .seanhess.net, and .ryan.seanhess.net doesn't work either.  Thanks anyway, it looks like it may be a problem with the server setup, I'll see.

Comment: @FrizbeeFanatic14 Maybe this article can help: http://shiflett.org/blog/2011/mar/php-session-debugging

Comment: I found the problem - the save directory for the PHP sessions was a root apache directory, and I'm runnin nginx fastcgi.  I just changed the root permissions for the folder and it works.  Thanks a ton for all of your help.

Comment: What do you mean a very interesting article? It links to http://PHP%20Session%20Debugging

Comment: @NobleUplift Very strange, I am pretty sure I put in a valid link at the time. But I think I wanted to link to the article that I have now linked to...