# Session is saved when page load is triggered by PHP, but not when triggered by Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session, cookies

I'm using cURL to login into a site. [Edit: They set a cookie and generate a token. I grab their token. Do some calculations with it and login. That's why keeping the session open is important.] I have a file that loads another one. Here it is in PHP:

**file1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var'] = $var;

header("Location: file2.php");

?>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$var = $_SESSION['var'];

?>
```

That works, however, I have to use Javascript to do some calculations and then I pass those variables to file2.php using GET (and there's one variable that's a session variable). So:

**file1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var'] = $var;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var var1 = 'car';
window.location = "file2.php?var1=" + var1;
</script>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$var1= $_GET['var1'];
$var2 = $_SESSION['var'];
?>
```

I tried `window.location.href` instead of `window.location`
I also tried using `document.cookie` and trying to setcookie (with `setcookie("PHPSESSID", [string]`) to what was stored in PHPSESSID (the other variables - JSESSIONID and `session_id`- were both NULL). I tried setting it to the entire string.

I tried

```
session_name('login_session');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
session_start();
```

that I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438521. At the start of the scripts on both pages.

I also tried `session_write_close();` at the end of the php script in **file1.php**.

---

Update. I've been reading through and thought if I used Ajax/jquery, I might be able to get it to work. I tried:

**file1.php**

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
</head></html>

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var'] = $var;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var var1 = 'car';

 function runLogin() {  
 $.ajax({  
 <strike>type: "GET",</strike>
 type: "POST",  
 url: "file2.php",  
 <strike>data: "var="+var1</strike>
 data: {'var': var1}
 });  
 }

 runLogin();
</script>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
<strike>$var1= $_GET['var1'];</strike>
$var1 = $_REQUEST;
$var2 = $_SESSION['var'];
?>
```

But the session was still lost. The first time I ran it I did the above. The second I added `include_once('file2.php');` in file1.php under session_start() and the opposite in file2.php

---

Solved:

**file1.php**

```
<?php
$session = session_id();
$_SESSION['var'] = var;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var var1= "<?=$session ?>";

function runLogin(session) {  
 $.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "file2.php",  
data: {'session': session}
 });  
}

runLogin(var1);

</script>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php 
$posted = $_REQUEST;
$sew = $posted['session'];
session_id($sew);
session_start();

$var = $_SESSION['var'];
?>
```

I searched my history but couldn't find the page I found the idea on.

Comment: you might need to add a `window.init = 'myfunction'` and then inside of the `myfunction` do your variable setting and redirect...

Comment: How can I keep the session live?

Comment: Save the session ID and then pass it to the new page using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the `$` in your variable:
`$_SESSION['var'] = var;` and `var var1;` is never set

**file1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var'] = 'your_var_value';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "file2.php?var1=<?php echo $_SESSION['var'];?>";
</script>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$var1 = (isset($_GET['var1'])?$_GET['var1']:null);
$var2 = (isset($_SESSION['var'])?$_SESSION['var']:null);
?>
```

Comment: No. I just checked my code. The above is just a shorter/refined version.

Answer (score 0):

But this is not a good practice for follow up and becarfull initialize some value to `$var`

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var'] = $var;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var var1 = "<?php echo $_SESSION['var']; ?>";
window.location = "file2.php?var1=" + var1;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing file1.php with cURL? cURL does not contain a Javascript interpreter, so none of the Javascript will be executed.

Comment: No. In file1, I grab the page with the token using cURL and leave the session open (unclosed). Then I do the calculations (Javascript). In file2, I post with login creds.